# Including a defined term in quotation marks

Tags: python, import, urllib, function, python-3.5

There is a game which I play a lot of called ROBLOX and since the update, you can not save your avatar. I used python to take the coding of the website (because you can still view it you just cant save it) and made it so that it saves it to your computer.
I **defined** the terms:

- CharacterID (as the ID of the user)

http://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/user-avatar?userId=19088261&thumbnailFormatId=124&width=352&height=352

(My ID being 19088261 (I found that URL in the coding))

- Robloxian (as the username of the player)

---

I tried to use this to open and save the image:

```
import urllib

Robloxian = int(input("First off, before we start, what's your roblox username?: "))
CharacterID = int(input("ID: "))
URL = "http://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/user-avatar?userId=(CharacterID)&thumbnailFormatId=124&width=352&height=352"
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, "(Robloxian)s Avatar.jpg"))
```

How can I make it download the image?

Comment: Which quotation marks?

Comment: If you're trying to insert the character id and username into later strings, please look up Python and string formatting.

Comment: The quotation marks in the URL and .jpg file name on line 5 and 6. I have (characterID) in the URL because I want it to change to the ID which the person writes as the integer when it asks and then for the file name to change to their username. i.e. tommygibsons2740's Avatar.jpg

Comment: Why is your question tagged [python-3.5]?  `urllib.urlretrieve` was last seen in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

`(` and `)` are *parentheses* (singular: parenthesis), not `"`quotation marks`"` (which I've surrounded with actual quotation marks).  Neither parentheses nor quotation marks will interpolate one string into another in Python... maybe you were thinking of some other language?

I suggest you (re-)read "[The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)", which includes an [introduction to strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and a section on [fancier output formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

The official Python documentation includes more formal definitions of [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), and the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).  These are typically invoked by using a string's [`.format` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

(There is also an older [`printf`-style string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting), which might be more familiar to you if you have a background in C or C-derived languages like Java and PERL.  If you don't know it already, the only reason to learn it would be to recognize it in older Python code.)

Strings can also be glued together with the `+` operator:

```
url = url_prefix + character_id + url_suffix
```

Here's a stripped-down version demonstrating where you want to go with this:

```
import urllib

character_id = raw_input('Roblox character ID: ')
url_template = 'http://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/user-avatar?userId={0:s}&thumbnailFormatId=124&width=352&height=352'
url = url_template.format(character_id)
file_name = character_id + '.html'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

Changes to note:

1. Use `raw_input` in Python 2 (renamed to just `input` in Python 3).  It's not only safer, but it always returns the data type you want: a string.  All that messing about with `int` was a waste of time.
2. `url_template` is the "containing" string, with `{0:s}` marking where some other string will be inserted (in this case, the character's ID number).
3. The template string's `.format` method returns a new string, which is later used with `urlretrieve`.
4. `file_name` is simple enough that I just stuck the two strings together with `+`.
5. I've followed the semi-official [*Style Guide for Python Code*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (a.k.a. "PEP 8"), specifically the "[Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)" section.
6. That roblox.com URL *doesn't retrieve an image*, but a bit of HTML that contains an `img` tag.  I've changed the filename to just the character ID and a ".html" extension.  (Why name the file after the user, when the avatar belongs to a specific character?)

Instead of downloading that HTML to a file, you'll probably want to store it in a string with [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen), and then parse that string (search this site for how) to get the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, and finally use `urlretrieve` to save *that* as a JPEG file.